# failed to start ... Qt platform plugin "xcb" on Raspbian Pi

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, pyinstaller

After creating an executable file in pi3 with pyinstaller I move my file to a pi4 device and try to execute it. But I got error says : **This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "".** I don't know what to do or how to get more detailed error message.

**EDIT:** `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1;`

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330499
}


In /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.11.3) [release]
"The plugin '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so' uses incompatible Qt library. (5.11.3) [release]" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330499
}


In /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.11.3) [release]
"The plugin '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so' uses incompatible Qt library. (5.11.3) [release]" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330499
}


In /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.11.3) [release]
"The plugin '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so' uses incompatible Qt library. (5.11.3) [release]" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330499
}


In /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.11.3) [release]
"The plugin '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so' uses incompatible Qt library. (5.11.3) [release]" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330499
}


In /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.11.3) [release]
"The plugin '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so' uses incompatible Qt library. (5.11.3) [release]" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330499
}


In /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.11.3) [release]
"The plugin '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so' uses incompatible Qt library. (5.11.3) [release]" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330499
}


In /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.11.3) [release]
"The plugin '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so' uses incompatible Qt library. (5.11.3) [release]" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/Desktop/format/3.6/doga_v1/platforms" ...
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

**EDIT2:** this is output from RPi3. Script works here

````
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/Desktop/desktop/testpyi/dist/doga_v1/platforms" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
loaded library "Xcursor"
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-egl-integration.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-egl-integration.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.Xcb.QXcbGlIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.5",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb_egl"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QXcbEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb_egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/Desktop/desktop/testpyi/dist/doga_v1/xcbglintegrations" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-egl-integration.so"
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platformthemes" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platformthemes/libqgtk2.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platformthemes/libqgtk2.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformThemeFactoryInterface.5.1",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "gtk2"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QGtk2ThemePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("gtk2")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platformthemes/libqgtk3.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platformthemes/libqgtk3.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformThemeFactoryInterface.5.1",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "gtk3"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QGtk3ThemePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("gtk3")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platformthemes/libqt5ct.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platformthemes/libqt5ct.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformThemeFactoryInterface.5.1",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "qt5ct"
        ]
    },
    "className": "Qt5CTPlatformThemePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("qt5ct")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/Desktop/desktop/testpyi/dist/doga_v1/platformthemes" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platformthemes/libqt5ct.so"
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/styles" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/styles/libbb10styleplugin.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/styles/libbb10styleplugin.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QStyleFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "bb10bright",
            "bb10dark"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QBB10StylePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("bb10bright", "bb10dark")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/styles/libqcleanlooksstyle.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/styles/libqcleanlooksstyle.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QStyleFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "cleanlooks"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QCleanlooksStylePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("cleanlooks")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/styles/libqgtk2style.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/styles/libqgtk2style.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QStyleFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "gtk2"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QGtk2StylePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("gtk2")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/styles/libqmotifstyle.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/styles/libqmotifstyle.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QStyleFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "motif",
            "cde"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QMotifStylePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("motif", "cde")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/styles/libqplastiquestyle.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/styles/libqplastiquestyle.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QStyleFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "plastique"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QPlastiqueStylePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("plastique")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/styles/libqt5ct-style.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/styles/libqt5ct-style.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QStyleFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "qt5ct-style"
        ]
    },
    "className": "Qt5CTStylePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("qt5ct-style")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/Desktop/desktop/testpyi/dist/doga_v1/styles" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforminputcontexts" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libcomposeplatforminputcontextplugin.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libcomposeplatforminputcontextplugin.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPlatformInputContextFactoryInterface.5.1",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "compose",
            "xim"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QComposePlatformInputContextPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("compose", "xim")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libibusplatforminputcontextplugin.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libibusplatforminputcontextplugin.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPlatformInputContextFactoryInterface.5.1",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "ibus"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QIbusPlatformInputContextPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("ibus")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/Desktop/desktop/testpyi/dist/doga_v1/platforminputcontexts" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libcomposeplatforminputcontextplugin.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/styles/libqt5ct-style.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/styles/libqgtk2style.so"
Cannot load library gtk-x11-2.0: (gtk-x11-2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
Device ID: 202481588433423
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/imageformats" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "gif"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/gif"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QGifPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("gif")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "ico",
            "cur"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QICOPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("ico", "cur")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "jpg",
            "jpeg"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/jpeg",
            "image/jpeg"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QJpegPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("jpg", "jpeg")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QImageIOHandlerFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "svg",
            "svgz"
        ],
        "MimeTypes": [
            "image/svg+xml"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QSvgPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("svg", "svgz")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/Desktop/desktop/testpyi/dist/doga_v1/imageformats" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so"
qt5ct: D-Bus system tray: no
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/bearer" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QBearerEngineFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "connman"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QConnmanEnginePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("connman")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/bearer/libqgenericbearer.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/bearer/libqgenericbearer.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QBearerEngineFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "generic"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QGenericEnginePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("generic")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/bearer/libqnmbearer.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/bearer/libqnmbearer.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QBearerEngineFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "networkmanager"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QNetworkManagerEnginePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("networkmanager")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/Desktop/desktop/testpyi/dist/doga_v1/bearer" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/bearer/libqgenericbearer.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/bearer/libqnmbearer.so"
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QWidget "widgetKeyboard2", which already has a layout
qt5ct: D-Bus global menu: no
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/iconengines" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QIconEngineFactoryInterface",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "svg",
            "svgz",
            "svg.gz"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QSvgIconPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329473
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("svg", "svgz", "svg.gz")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/Desktop/desktop/testpyi/dist/doga_v1/iconengines" ...
Could not parse stylesheet of object 0xf46818
Client Db Version: 21
Current Version On Server: 224
Current Version On Client: 226
requiredDbVersion 21 clientDbVersion 21
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/accessible" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/Desktop/desktop/testpyi/dist/doga_v1/accessible" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/plugins/accessiblebridge" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/pi/Desktop/desktop/testpyi/dist/doga_v1/accessiblebridge" ```
````

Comment: execute: `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1; ./your_executable`

Comment: The log indicates that you have used a version of Qt other than RPi3 than the one with RPi4, what version of Qt (PyQt5) did you use in RPi3?

Comment: I think its 5.11.2 on RPi3. How can I check it to be sure

Comment: Run the same code in RPI3 and you will see the version, in your log you can see that in RPi4 5.11.3 is used. Why do you generate a binary if you are going to use it in Linux? Why not create a package (setup.py) to redistribute your application without incompatibility issues? You should deploy with linuxdeployqt so that the system Qt is not used.

Comment: I am trying to create a package that works on different devices without need of any update on that devices. In theory after I create executable file it shoud'nt ask me any  packages in a different place. Because I already import all dependencies in that folder I make with pyinstaller. Am I wrong?

Comment: Pyinstaller create an executable but does not copy all the dependencies, I recommend using fbs that allows you to do that easily.